# Eureka - PushRow - disable 'go back' behavoir

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I use the following code to display a PushRow, which works really nice:

```
<<< PushRow<Sound>(){
  $0.title = "Sound"
  $0.options = manager.objects(Sound.self)
  $0.selectorTitle = "Select a sound"
  $0.displayValueFor = {
    return $0?.name
    }
  }
```

Now the thing is, the user is able to select sound here. I want to do something like in the iOS settings when you choose a ringtone for example: You  have a tableview and everytime you select a cell sound will be played. Now playing the sound is not the problem. 
But as soon as the user selects a row in the PushRow, the controller automatically goes back to the form. So I want to disable this behavior and play sound every time a cell is selected and let to user go back himself

Answer (score 0):

Just add these lines of code. Working fine as of now. This code disables the default "popViewController".
`$0.presentationMode = PresentationMode.show(controllerProvider: ControllerProvider.callback{return SelectorViewController(){_ in}}, onDismiss: nil)`